# IPC or command line?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, node.js, ipc

I'm creating a nodejs program that need to use some unix command.

I have two choices either execute them using `exec('command ...')` which just execute the command with the given arguments.

Or through IPC communication.

What are the benefits of using IPC instead of exec ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what that program is.
`Exec`ing incurs a cost associated with having to fork a child and load it (the actual system-level exec).
If you're going to be using that unix program a lot, like if you're writing a server, using IPC could allow you to pay that price only once but it's dependent on that unix program's ability to be run as a server in your IPC setup.

Comment: Rather than IPC I'd suggest a domain socket for this.

Comment: @ott Domain sockets ARE IPC.